# Web Deploy to Azure Web App in App Service Environment

Tags: azure, teamcity, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am experiencing a problem deploying to a Azure Web App hosted inside an App Service Environment (ASE) with an Internal Load Balancer (ILB) using the web deploy step in Team City.  It also fails when trying to deploy directly from my machine using Visual Studio.

Here's the error: "could not connect to the remote computer using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process is started on the remote computer."

This error is a bit misleading because, upon further investigation, the web app is returning (401) unauthorized error even though I am able to connect to SCM/Kudo using the credentials in the publishing profile.

The only way I have been able to deploy is via FTP after establishing a VPN connection.

After a lot of research, I found some other folks who were told to stop/start the site, etc., but that has not worked in this case. Do web apps act differently when hosted in an ASE? I have not run into this problem deploying to any other web app.

Any ideas on what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem here. I managed to deploy via FTP without VPN connection (from a VM on the same network as the ASE) but I haven't found the way to access Kudu.

Comment: Hi Neal, did you managed to have it work ? I'm experiencing the same problem here. We moved to ASE for security reasons, but our devops flow is broken in Vsts. The Azure App Service Deploy (msdeploy) cannot pushed the bits to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like msdeploy requires by default TLS 1.0 to be available. I bet your ASE have its TLS 1.0 deactivated. So you have two choices:

- re-activate TLS 1.0 in your ASE (potential security breach)
- configure your build agent (if you have access to it) to use TLS 1.1 and higher following the instructions [here](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2016/02/28/pci-compliant-web-deploy-getting-webdeploy-working-after-disabling-insecure-ciphers-like-ssl-30-and-tls-10)

Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050789/1303737)

Official Microsoft support [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3206898/enabling-iis-manager-and-web-deploy-after-disabling-ssl3-and-tls-1.0)