# Web Deploy to Azure fails "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: azure, ssl, cloud, webdeploy

I always deployed from my local machine to Azure (Classic cloud service) but from yesterday I get this error:

```
Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://[MYNAME].cloudapp.net:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site'.The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

The port is open. The web deploy is installed. As I see nothing has changed.
I tried to install a new version of Web Deploy (3.6) but it didn't help.

What else can be checked?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i faced the same problem: old 2008 r2 Server never changed anything

cause (speculation): since visual studio 15.9 they disabled SSL 2.0, TLS 1.0, etc. so it cant communicate propper with the old webdeploy

solution: enable TLS 1.2 on old webserver (and disable the old ones)

i found this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/384634/webdeploy-netcore-api-to-iis-vs159.html

which linked to this blog:
https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/

> Step 1 – Backup Registry Settings We strongly recommend taking a
>   backup of the registry before making any changes. Use below link to
>   find steps to how to export registry values.
>
> Step 2 – Enable TLS 1.2 on Windows You have two options to enable TLS
>   version on your system.
>
> Option 1 – Merge Resistry File Download the [Enable-TLS12-Windows.reg](https://tecadmin.net/wp-content/downloads/wincfg/Enable-TLS12-Windows.reg)
>   and [Enable-TLS12-TLS11-Windows.reg](https://tecadmin.net/wp-content/downloads/wincfg/Enable-TLS12-TLS11-Windows.reg) files on your Windows system. Now
>   right click on file and click Merge.

Step 3: restart.

PS: First i tried the "Client" way, which doesn't work for me. But maybe it helps some one:

I found the answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050789/9624651
and he referenced to this link https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2016/02/28/pci-compliant-web-deploy-getting-webdeploy-working-after-disabling-insecure-ciphers-like-ssl-30-and-tls-10

Answer (score -2):

Do have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-web-deploy-problems-with-visual-studio). I guess they have mentioned your problem

Comment: No, they don't.  I have this same problem (though to a Windows Server 2008 R2 server).  It has worked for the last *5 years!* without issue, an multiple updates via Web deploy a month.  Not one of the troubleshooting errors is related to SSL/TLS.