# WebDeploy from Visual Studio can not create SSL\TLS secure channel

Tags: visual-studio, azure, ssl-certificate, cloud, azure-cloud-services

Suddenly (at least I have no idea that were changes) I'm getting the following error during web deploy from Visual Studio 2017 to Azure classic Cloud service.

[image]

I re-checked the setting on Azure Portal:

[image]

and server itself:

[image]

Do you see some problem? What else can I check to fix the problem?

Comment: I found the solution here (editing registry): https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050789/452150