# WebDeploy from Visual Studio 2019 Can not create SSL\TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2019, webdeploy

I'm getting error, when trying to Validate Connection or Publish my changes to server using WebDeploy from Visual Studio 2019.
My OS is Windows 10 Pro 1903.

[image: visual studio 2019 web deploy settings]

I'm hosting website on https://www.smarterasp.net/ and their technical support virified that the issue is not on their side, since they successfully logged in using my Web Deploy credentials. So the issue is located in my system.

I've already tried solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048583/changed-ssl-tls-on-server-cannot-publish-via-visual-studio-now/40050789#40050789) by adding Registry keys, but the issue remains.

OS reintall is not an option. 
Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio reinstall resolved the issue.